# Maven Google App Engine Guice Class Not Found Exception (although jar present in WEB-INF)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, guice, classnotfoundexception

I have a Java project that essentially is made up of three main parts:

1. A web server application using the Google App Engine -> war ( *fs_primeranks_server* )
2. A client application for the desktop -> JAR (*fs_proxy*)
3. An Android app that connects to the web server. (*fs_replay*)
4. A bonus module containing common jar class library containing the common data object representation. (*fs_data*)

I started out with creating the project in InteliJ IDEA. I got to the current point and then made the change to maven. However, making the change the server component is no longer running. It compiles, but throws a *Class Not Found* exception. As previously with the InteliJ IDEA project files everything was running fine I am quite sure my problems are with how my maven files are set up. Nevertheless, after hours of research and looking I'm still unable to correct it. So any ideas?

[The project files hosted on github.](https://github.com/gaborbernat/fs_viewer).

[The output of the Maven build process, plus the gae:run command (with  the exception).](http://pastebin.com/WsNEJV3n) (the warning starts like:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.primeranks.fs_server.GuiceConfigFsPrimeranksServer)

Image of the file structure after build. Jar files and class files seem okay.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, bad web configuration file. The path for the startup class was wrong, hence the class not found exception. :(